# @font face weird issue between urls

Tags: url, font-face, opencart, webfonts

I been having a weird issue with a client's website.  Depending if you type "www" or not, the font comes up differently, even if you refresh the page.  I wanted to know if anyone else had this issue and how to work around it?

Shows the correct font:
http://artisseriebakery.com/

Shows the incorrect font:
http://www.artisseriebakery.com/

I did this site in opencart and the font is a custom webfont, so I don't know if it's a linking problem.

Comment: Do a View/Source from the browser for each of the pages, and then do a diff on the resulting text files.  This should tell you what the differences are.  What is clear is that the two URLs are serving two slightly different pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using IE8 at the moment and I see no issues with your fonts... But it sounds like a cache issue.

I found a free extension for opencart that will clear all cache, you could give that a try as well.

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=5187&filter_search=cache

### *** Edit Below

Try adding an .htaccess file to the folder where your fonts are located with this in it:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">   
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>     
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"   
    </IfModule> 
</FilesMatch>
```

I think this should clear up your Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) issues with fonts. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I don't think it's a cache issue, at least not with my browser (I was able to reproduce).

Comment: You may be right, but I'm at work with no way to test it... I edited my answer to include a workaround for CORS issues. That may also be the problem.